# iPhone 6 Battery quickly drains and jumps battery percentage

Tags: battery, charging, iphone

I have this battery problem with my iphone 6(10.0) for over a month now. At 100% battery, it drains very quickly and most of the time the battery percentage jumps from 60% to 30% etc. And from 20% when the warning shows it then jumps to 1%.

I already tried draining iphone and fully charging it then reset the phone. I want to update the os but I need 10.0 in my work. Does my iphone battery have any chance working again properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the symptom of a weakened iPhone battery that is failing (especially on iOS 10). My recommendation is to determine your battery's current capacity and health by downloading a couple of battery health apps. You can monitor your battery health to determine if you need to replace the battery soon.

If replacement is needed but your iPhone is not under warranty or AppleCare, you can replace the battery yourself for about $35 (battery and proper tools). I was having these issues with my iPhone 6+ and replaced the battery which was not too difficult. My phone is like new now.

Comment: I knew it! Meaning, this will not be resolved even if I update my phone to the latest version?

Comment: The latest version did not fix this battery drain on my iphone but a new battery did completely resolve the problem. That being said, iOS 10 does not appear to report battery percentage well on older batteries, as many people are experiencing these fluctuating changes in battery percentage soon after updating to iOS 10. Perhaps a future update may improve the situation.

Comment: Per media reports today, Apple confirms degrading performance of older devices in various situations including those with weakened batteries. Apparently this was by design to have device owners either upgrade, or in the case of a battery, fix the problem before the battery dies.

Comment: that's why I switched to android (samsung).